# Find the cardinality of $A= \left\{ f : \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N \mid \forall x:f(x)\le x\right\}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How can I solve tasks like this one?

### Example task

> Find the cardinality of
>    $$A= \left\{ f : \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N \mid \forall x:f(x)\le x\right\}.$$

I know that $|A| \le \mathfrak{c}$
but how to deal with lower bound?

Comment: The term in English is "cardinality" not "power"

Comment: @Holo On the contrary, "power" is also a common expression for cardinality.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo really? Because when I only started studying set theory I used power, and couldn't find almost anything. You learn something new every day

Comment: Interesting. I have never heard the word "power" used for "cardinality."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that the set $\{f:\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}\mid f(0)=0\}=B⊆A$, so $|A|≥|B|=2^{|\Bbb N|}=\frak c$

Comment: Ah, it is really clever. I am learning how to solve tasks like that. There I can find subset of my set and it works. Can you tell me - can I use similar trick as you showed in finding cardinality of $ B = \left\{ f \in A | S(f,\mathbb N)   \right\} $ where $S(f,C)$ means that $f$ is surjective to $C$? I suspect that no because I can't define surjective by one "prefunction" but maybe I am wrong

Comment: @VirtualUser surjective functions are always harder to work with. For this case the easiest way I can see is: let $f$ be in $A$ such that $f\restriction_{\Bbb N\setminus\{2^n\mid n\in \Bbb N\}}$ is surjective. Now for each $g$ in $A$ define $h_g(x)=\begin{cases} f(x)&x\ne 2^n\\g(n)&x=2^n\end{cases}$, you can notice that for all $g$ we have $h_g\in B$, and if $g\ne g'$ then $h_g\ne h_{g'}$, so you found a lower bound: $|A|=\frak c$

Comment: Thanks, I think that I have understood this way of thinking. Now I am going to solve some tasks like this, sometimes if I will have doubts I will post to that forum (of course with my solution, for corectness-checking). Thanks @Holo!